# Get user id after log-in

Tags: php, mysql

After successful login, I would like the function to keep the user_id, so the user can update their the profile in the database. In the database there are two rows called catchphrase and interest. Right now when I write something it creates a new column with user_id 0.

I get this error as well: Notice: Array to string conversion in

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modul8B/models/profile_table_class.php on line 23
```

Line 23 is:

```
$data = array ($catchphrase, $interest, $image);
```

Here's the code for inserting:

```
class Profile_Table {
    private $db; 

    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->db = $pdo; 
        ;
    }
        public function getProfileForUser($user_id){
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, catchphrase, interest, image FROM user
            WHERE user_id = ?";  
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $data = array( $user_id);
        $statement->execute($data);
        //print_r($statement);
        return $statement->fetchObject();
    }

    public function insertProfile($catchphrase, $interest, $image){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (catchphrase, interest, image) values ('".$catchphrase."', '".$interest."', '".$image."')";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $data = array ($catchphrase, $interest, $image);  
        $statement->execute ($data);
        return $statement;      
    }
```

and here's the home page:

```
<?php
if ($siteVisitor->IsLoggedIn()) {
    //echo "catchphrase = $catchphrase<br>";
    include_once "models/profile_table_class.php";
    $profiles = new Profile_Table($db);
    $userId = $siteVisitor->getId();
    $profileData = $profiles->getProfileForUser($userId);

    //die();
    $homeOutput = include_once 'views/loggedIn.php';
    $homeOutput .= include_once "views/profile-list-html.php";
    $profileIsSubmitted = isset($_POST['profile-submit']);
    if ($profileIsSubmitted) {
        $catchphrase = $_POST['catchphrase'];
        $interest = $_POST['interest'];
        $image = $_FILES['image'];
        try {
            $profiles->insertProfile($catchphrase, $interest, $image);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $errorDescription = $e;
            echo $e;
        }
    }
    return $homeOutput;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: U should move your DB actions to a seperate class

Comment: You are using prepared statements inside insertProfile() wrong - possible SQL injections. Check some examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @va5ja I am aware of the SQL injections. Can you point out how am I using the statements wrong?

Comment: You don't have any binding points like ? or :image. This $data array doesn't do anything. You can correct to (?, ?, ?).

Comment: what should I use instead of the $data then? Is there any other option or how should I modify my script?

Comment: I get this as well error as well Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modul8B/models/profile_table_class.php on line 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `getProfileForUser` method you are using a parameter for the user_id:

```
user_id = ?
```

And in the `insertProfile` method you are not:

```
('".$catchphrase."', '".$interest."', '".$image."')
```

Which is an inconsistency, and unsafe.
Using named parameters `:name` will make your code much more readable (more safe), so i would advice to use them if you want.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Here's the code for that:

```
public function getProfileForUser($user_id){
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, catchphrase, interest, image FROM user WHERE user_id = :user_id";  
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(
        ':user_id' => $user_id
    );
    $statement->execute($parameters);
    return $statement->fetchObject();
}

public function insertProfile($catchphrase, $interest, $image){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (catchphrase, interest, image) values (:catchprase, :interest, :image)";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(
        ':catchprase' => $catchphrase,
        ':interest' => $interest,
        ':image' => $image
    );
    $statement->execute($parameters);
    return $statement;      
}
```

Another thing, do not upload files in your database *which i think is causing your array to string error*, upload only a reference to the image and move the file to an images directory in your app:

```
if ($siteVisitor->IsLoggedIn()) {
    include_once "models/profile_table_class.php";
    $profiles = new Profile_Table($db);
    $userId = $siteVisitor->getId();
    $profileData = $profiles->getProfileForUser($userId);

    //die();
    $homeOutput = include_once 'views/loggedIn.php';
    $homeOutput .= include_once "views/profile-list-html.php";
    $profileIsSubmitted = isset($_POST['profile-submit']);

    if ($profileIsSubmitted) {
        $catchphrase = $_POST['catchphrase'];
        $interest = $_POST['interest'];

        $image_directory = '/uploads'; // destination folder
        $image = $_FILES['image']; 
        $imageRef = '';

        if ($image['error'] < 0) {

            $image_tmp_name = $image['tmp_name'];
            $image_name = $image['name'];
            $imageRef = $image_directory .'/'. $image_name;

            // Move the file: Source, destination
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, $imageRef);
        }

        try {
            $profiles->insertProfile($catchphrase, $interest, $imageRef);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $errorDescription = $e;
            echo $e;
        }
    }
    return $homeOutput;
```